# Interpreting the format of a SLF4J log message

Tags: logging, slf4j, apache-zookeeper

Here's the log message:

```
2016-10-12 22:07:03,114 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@192] - Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:55102
```

I don't understand what the `NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@192` element is referencing. Can somebody explain how to interpret it -- Are the different parts separated by the colons? Is there some sort of hierarchical order to the parts?

Answer (score 0):

The format is `["thread name":"class name"@"line of code executed"],` so in this case `NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181` is the thread name and `NIOServerCnxnFactory` is the class name.